# Write jasmine test case for jquery code in controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine

I have a controller class in AngularJS and it contains method containing jquery code. I want to write Jasmine test case for it, but not sure how to do it for jquery code.

Controller

```
    $scope.changeInfoType = function() {
        var pubInfo = $("#infoType option:selected").text();
        if (pubInfo === 'Publication')
            $('#pubType').prop('disabled', false);
        else
            $('#pubType').prop('disabled', true);
    };
```

HTML

```
    <div>
    <select ng-model="infoTypeVal" style="width: 300px;height: 22px"  ng-options="infoType.title  for infoType in informationTypes" id="infoType"  ng-change="changeInfoType()"></select>
    </div>

    <div>
    <select ng-model="pubTypeVal"  style="width: 300px;height: 22px" ng-options="pubType.title  for pubType in publicationTypes" id="pubType" disabled="true" ></select>
    </div>
```

Comment: simple answer is don't use jQUery. Should be working with the model. Try  using `ng-disabled` based on `infoTypeVal`

Comment: In angular applicationds you should work with DOM only in directives, because 1) it is the desired place to do it 2) working with DOM in controller could lead to problems with extending it and testing, as I've seen in my projects. In your simple case you should use ng-disabled, as @charlietfl have already proposed